# Generating a wordlist in C++

Tags: c++, word-list

I am trying to figure out how to generate a word list in C++ based on a string of characters given (similar to how [crunch wordlist](https://sourceforge.net/projects/crunch-wordlist/) works)

I am fairly new to C++ and have only gotten the program to list the characters off one at a time.

I've been searching online for quite some time with not much luck other than finding O(n^2) with not much idea on how to implement it to the program.

Code:

```
int main() {
    string characters = "abcde";

    int length = 5;
    string word = "";
    for(int i = word.length(); i <= length; i++) {
        for(int l = 0; l < characters.length(); l++) {
            word += characters[l];
            cout << word << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Wanted Result: http://pastebin.com/tgyUtKfA

Snippet of result:

```
a
b
c
d
e
aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
ba
bb
bc
bd
be
ca
cb
cc
cd
ce
da
db
dc
dd
de
ea
eb
ec
ed
ee
aaa
```

(The final result follows that pattern down to "eeeee")

Comment: Pastebin is blocked at work - which nicely illustrates why we require questions to be self-contained. Please paste the desired result into the question. (If it is very large, please trim down the number of inputs to get a more reasonable desired output.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Comment: @BoBTFish I looked at the list. It is simply a permutation of all possible letter combinations of the given letters in strings from length 1 up through length 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<string> make_permutations(int length) {
  if (length == 0) {
    return vector<string>{};
  }
  vector<string> results;
  vector<string> children = make_permutations(length - 1);
  for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) { 
    results.emplace_back(1, letter);
    for(auto child : children) {
      results.push_back(std::string(1, letter) + child);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

int main()
{
 auto results = make_permutations(2);
    for(auto s : results) cout << s << endl;
}
```

live: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gGVAxbVUFVZs4fUR

Comment: for(letter = 'a'..'z') expects ';' before 'z'?

Comment: Now with 100% real code.  There's plenty of fat, though, as making strings like this is quite inefficient.

Comment: Im getting 'emplace_back' not resolved. Any idea why?

Comment: you're not using c++11 or later:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back   if you look at my link to wandbox, see how it says -std=gnu++1z  that tells the compiler what to use.   -std=c++14 would also work and is compatible with clang, as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
// dyndict.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

class CDynDict
{
public:
    CDynDict();
    ~CDynDict();

    void Reset(const string& source, int minout, int maxout);
    bool Next(string& str);

private:
    string _source;
    int _outlen, _minout, _maxout;
    vector<int> _vecdict;
    mutex _mutex;
};

CDynDict::CDynDict()
{
}

CDynDict::~CDynDict()
{
}

void CDynDict::Reset(const string& source, int minout, int maxout)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> locker(_mutex);
    _source = source;
    _minout = minout;
    _maxout = maxout;   
    if (_minout > _maxout)
        swap(_minout, _maxout);
    _outlen = minout;
    _vecdict.resize(_outlen);
}

bool CDynDict::Next(string& str)
{
    int i = 0, carry = 1; 
    int lsrc = _source.length();
    unique_lock<mutex> locker(_mutex);

    if (_vecdict.size() == 0 || _outlen > _maxout)
        return false;

    str.clear();
    while (i <_outlen) str += _source[_vecdict[i++]];

    for (i = _outlen-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {   
        if (carry == 0) break;
        _vecdict[i] += carry;
        carry = _vecdict[i] / lsrc;
        if (carry > 0 && i > 0) _vecdict[i] %= lsrc;
    }       

    if (_vecdict[0] >= lsrc)
    {   
        _vecdict.resize(++_outlen);
        _vecdict.assign(_outlen, 0);
    }       
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CDynDict dict;
    string str;

    dict.Reset("abcde", 1, 4);

    while (dict.Next(str))
        cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be better by explaining what is actually happening. This would be helpful for the OP who stated that they're faily new to C++.